# How to enable PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress event when set textbox.Focus() on textbox_LostFocus event in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, keyboard

How to enable

> PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress

event when set **textbox.Focus() on textbox_LostFocus** event in windows phone 8.
I want to show keyboard when i add some item into listbox from textbox. Listbox gets update but my keyboard always gets hide on button click.
I want to make it open all the time till i press back key.

Thanks,
Nishant

Comment: You should start accepting some of the answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can get **BackKeyPress** Event by :

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```

You can write **textbox.Focus()** at the end of button click when all work is done

try this :

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListboxName.Items.Add(TextBoxName.Text);
    TextBoxName.Text = "";
    TextBoxName.Focus();
}
```

I have implemented. Its working...

Comment: I have tried but it's also not working. Actually what i do is I have a textbox, a listbox and a button on a page. When i write something in textbox and click on button then it updates my listbox and add one more row in existing list. Its working fine but the problem is whenever i press button, the keyboard gets hide. I want that it should not be happens. Everytime i have to tap on textbox to open keyboard. It should hide only if i press back button.

Comment: It's not working at my side because i used
'ListBox.UpdateLayout();
ListBox.ScrollIntoView(ListBox.Items[ListBox.Items.Count - 1]);'
So my textbox hide behind keyboard.

Comment: Where did you use `ListBox.UpdateLayout(); ListBox.ScrollIntoView(ListBox.Items[ListBox.Items.Count - 1]);` can you add the code where you used it?

Comment: I think that code is not needed. IT would be automatically Updated. just use above code. I had taken only listbox, Textbox and button in Page and Implemented above code. It is working from my side properly